# retrieving unique entries from a mysql table with distinct

Tags: distinct, duplicate-detection

inside a mysql table there are several classifieds with the rows ID, title, advertiser_id

In order to omit duplicated content inside my sitemap  I am trying to retrieve a list where title and advertiser are unique.

My sql stmt looks like this:

```
SELECT distinct concat(cl.title, cl.advertiser_id) AS uniques, cl.ID ...
```

unfortunatelly this does not work as expected. The result looks like this:

```
uniques                                     ID      title   
Mobile Wellnessmassage ( Kreis Soest)58091  26608   Mobile Wellnessmassage ( Kreis Soest)
Mobile Wellnessmassage ( Kreis Soest)58091  24465   Mobile Wellnessmassage ( Kreis Soest)
```

Any ideas how I could restrict the result to a dataset with uniques?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

No, it works as it need to works. You are getting back 2 records, because ID is not the same.
If you leave the `cl.ID`, you will get back only one record. Try it.

Comment: this is true. But I also need cl.ID and other values.

Comment: you try to achive something, what you can not. `DISTINCT` means distinct. Let's use 2 queries. First for the `DISTINCT` things, second for the ID-s.